# Check Session Iframe OpenIDConnect

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have a situation where I have an RP that does not explicitly require you to be logged into it. However I had a look at the session management specification for Open ID Connect, more specifically the `check_session_iframe` endpoint specification as drafted [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)

I was wondering if the following scenario would be possible. I have an RP that uses client x to federate sign on onto my OP. Is it possible such that I can see if the client (x) is signed into the OP even if you do not have the session id (or `sid`). In otherwords is it possible for an application to see if you have a session with the OP so that you are not forced to prompt a sign on against the OP.

A basic flow that I want to satisfy for UX reasons is

1) go to RP.

2) check to see if RP has session with OP.

3) - If there is a session then auto-login (without initiating flow)

- If there is no session then don't do anything(ie no need to prompt for login).

Is something like this possible? I do understand that it is possible to get session information if you have previously been signed in (by using the given `session_state` and `client_id`)

I have looked at the IdentityServer3.Samples, more specifically the client sample that shows how you can check session state [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient) however it seems like this sample shows how it is possible to check session state after doing a log in. I want to know if it is possible to check if the client currently does have a session even before the RP explicitly requests for sign on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `prompt=none` in the authorization request to the OP, and do it in an iframe. The oidc-client-js library now supports with the `querySessionStatus` API this as of recent: https://brockallen.com/2016/08/12/check-session-support-in-oidc-client-js/.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **querySessionStatus** methon to chec if there is an active session

i've added a method in my oidc-client service

```
sessionStatus(): Promise<any> {
  return this._userManager.querySessionStatus();
}
```

and i called this method to check if there is a valid session in my CanActivate guard, if session exist i call **signinRedirect** directly without prompting the login view

```
 canActivate(): boolean {
   if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
    this.authService.getSessionStatus().then((data) => {
      if (data.sid !== null) { // if session exist i call login method in my oidc-client service
       this.authService.login();
       return true;
      } else {
       this.router.navigate(['account/login']);
       return false;
    }
    }).catch((err) => {
     this.router.navigate(['account/login']);
     return false;
   });

  } else {
    return true;
  }
 }
```